# mongoose populate returns null array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Mongoose isnt playing very well with population.  this is my model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);

var userSchema = new Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String,
  books: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}]
  }
);

var bookSchema = new Schema({
  bookid: {type:String, unique:true, required:true},
  imgURL: String
});

module.exports.user = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports.book = mongoose.model('Book', bookSchema);
```

The database looks correct.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56a17cd70a498fcc37cdbe60"), "username" : "test", "password" : "test", "books" : [ ObjectId("56a17d21d43dc32a3a9837de"), ObjectId("56a17ee5d43dc32a3a9837e4"), ObjectId("56a17f5dd43dc32a3a9837e6"), ObjectId("56a17f9fd43dc32a3a9837e8") ], "__v" : 4 }
```

But when I do a populate I get an empty 'books' array

```
users.findOne({'_id':userid}).populate('books').exec(function(err,data){
            if (err) return console.error(err);

            if(data){

            }
});
```

Everything is there it simply will not populate.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the incorrect `ref` in the `userSchema`, it should reference to `book` schema rather than `user` schema itself.

```
var book = mongoose.model('Book', bookSchema);

...
books: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'book'}]
```